What's a fast way to identify all overlapping sets?
I need to identify and consolidate all intersecting sets so that I ultimately have completely discrete sets that share no values between them.  The sets currently exist as values in a dictionary, and the dictionary keys are sorted by priority that needs to be preserved.
For example, starting with the following sets in dictionary d:
d = {'b': {'b', 'f', 'a'},
     'x': {'x'},
     's': {'s'},
     'a': {'a', 'f', 'e'},
     'e': {'e'},
     'f': {'f'},
     'z': {'x', 'z'},
     'g': {'g'}}

...I'm trying to consolidate the sets to:
{'b': {'a', 'b', 'e', 'f'},
 'x': {'x', 'z'},
 's': {'s'},
 'a': {'a', 'b', 'e', 'f'},
 'e': {'a', 'b', 'e', 'f'},
 'f': {'a', 'b', 'e', 'f'},
 'z': {'x', 'z'},
 'g': {'g'}}

...by consolidating any sets that overlap with other sets.
I have code that gets me to these results:
d_size = {k:len(v) for (k, v) in d.items()}
static = False
while not static:
    for (k, vs) in d.items():
        for v in vs:
            if v == k: continue
            d[v].update(vs)

    static = True
    for (k, v) in d_size.items():
        if len(d[k]) != v:
            d_size[k] = len(d[k])
            static = False

. . . but it is prohibitively slow for the sizes of datasets it needs to handle which regularly extend into a few hundred thousand rows with set sizes of arbitrary lengths but usually less than 50 after the consolidations are complete.
Ultimately I then need to remove the duplicate sets, ensuring that I keep the first appearance in the dictionary as the keys are sorted by priority, so the final result for this toy example set would be:
{'b': {'a', 'b', 'e', 'f'}, 'x': {'x', 'z'}, 's': {'s'}, 'g': {'g'}}
I only need this final dictionary for my purposes, so am open to any solutions that don't produce the intermediary dictionary with duplicate sets.
Lastly, these results are mapped back into a pandas dataframe, so am open to using solutions incorporating pandas (or numpy).  Any other third-party packages would need to be balanced by weighing their footprint against their benefit.

I think this describes union-find, for an incremental solution, disjoint-set.

This is a graph problem, you can use networkx.connected_components:
# pip install networkx
import networkx as nx

# make graph
G = nx.from_dict_of_lists(d)

# identify connected components
sets = {n: c for c in nx.connected_components(G) for n in c}

# keep original order
out = {n: sets[n] for n in d}

Output:
{'b': {'a', 'b', 'e', 'f'},
 'x': {'x', 'z'},
 's': {'s'},
 'a': {'a', 'b', 'e', 'f'},
 'e': {'a', 'b', 'e', 'f'},
 'f': {'a', 'b', 'e', 'f'},
 'z': {'x', 'z'},
 'g': {'g'}}

If you just need the first key, you could replace the last step with:
out = {}
seen = set()
for k in d:
    if k not in seen:
        out[k] = sets[k]
        seen.update(sets[k])

Alternatively use min with a dictionary of weights to identify the first key per group:
import networkx as nx

# make graph
G = nx.from_dict_of_lists(d)

weights = {k: i for i, k in enumerate(d)}
# {'b': 0, 'x': 1, 's': 2, 'a': 3, 'e': 4, 'f': 5, 'z': 6, 'g': 7}

out = {min(c, key=weights.get): c for c in nx.connected_components(G)}

Output:
{'b': {'a', 'b', 'e', 'f'}, 'x': {'x', 'z'}, 's': {'s'}, 'g': {'g'}}

pure python solution:
out = {}
mapper = {}
seen = set()

for k, s in d.items():
    if (common := s & seen):
        out[mapper[next(iter(common))]].update(s)
    else:
        out[k] = s
        mapper.update(dict.fromkeys(s, k))
        seen.update(s)

print(out)
# {'b': {'a', 'b', 'e', 'f'}, 'x': {'x', 'z'}, 's': {'s'}, 'g': {'g'}}


This is amazing, thank you @mozway!  The networkx.connected_components is doing exactly what I needed and DRASTICALLY reducing my code's run time on larger sets.  Thank you!!!
